# JSON Parsing using struct

Tags: go

How to parse below two JSON and print values of "c"

```
1)
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": 123
        },
        "b": {
            "c": 456
        }
    }
}
```

```
2)
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": 444
        }
    }
}
```

Below struct help in parsing but then how to iterate over b, it is not array?
Please help.

```
type Data struct {
    A struct {
        B struct {
            C int `json:"c"`
        } `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}
```

Comment: Because the "a" value in 1) has duplicate keys, the application will need to walk through the "a" value with [More](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.More) and [Token](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token) to extract the multiple "c" values.

Comment: The first one is an invalid json.

Comment: The first example is valid, but is not guaranteed to be interoperable.  See the [JSON RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159.html#section-4) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Cerise Limón and  Minji

There is JSON.RawMessage type which solved the issue
That invalid JSON format is received from third party API so cant change that.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type DatainC struct {
    C int `json:"c"`
}

type Data struct {
    A json.RawMessage `json:"a"`
}

func main() {

    blob := `{
        "a": {
            "b": {
                "c": 123
            },
            "b": {
                "c": 456
            }
        }
    }`

    var abc Data

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(blob), &abc); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data, _ := abc.A.MarshalJSON()

    //log.Println("JSON Data", string(data))

    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string(data)))

    // read open bracket
    t, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", t, t)
    for dec.More() {

        t1, err1 := dec.Token()
        if err1 != nil {
            log.Fatal(err1)
        }
        if t1 == "b" {

            var c DatainC

            err2 := dec.Decode(&c)
            if err2 != nil {
                log.Fatal(err2)
            }
            fmt.Println("Value of C - ", c.C)

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Just be clear that you're not really dealing with JSON. You're dealing with a file format that someone may have decided to call JSON, may actually believe *is* JSON, but it breaks one of the rules of JSON which makes it an illegal JSON file. Simply put, this is not JSON.

Comment: Agree . Those guys were converting it from XML may be that created this invalid JSON

Comment: The JSON is **valid**, but is not guaranteed to be interoperable.  See the [JSON RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159.html#section-4) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

the first one is invalid json.
if you want to iterate over "b", should be like this

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": [
        {"c":123},
        {"c":456}
     ]}
}
```

then struct

```
type Data struct {
    A struct {
        B []struct {
            C int `json:"c"`
        } `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}
```

this [sites (auto generate convert json to struct)](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) may help you